# How to use redux-persist with toolkit and next-redux-wrapper?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

I'm having trouble with `redux-toolkit`, `redux-persist`, and `next-redux-wrapper` configuration. I've tried to make persist for redux state but it doesn't run redux actions which should save state to local storage.

My `store.ts` file.

```js
import {
  Action,
  combineReducers,
  configureStore,
  ThunkAction,
  getDefaultMiddleware,
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { createWrapper } from 'next-redux-wrapper';
import taskReducer from './reducers/taskReducer';
import projectReducer from './reducers/projectReducer';
import workplaceReducer from './reducers/workplaceReducer';
import userReducer from './reducers/userReducer';
import trackTaskReducer from './reducers/trackTaskReducer';
import chatRoomReducer from './reducers/chatRoomReducer';
import messageReducer from './reducers/messageReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  taskReducer,
  projectReducer,
  workplaceReducer,
  userReducer,
  trackTaskReducer,
  chatRoomReducer,
  messageReducer,
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const customizedMiddleware = getDefaultMiddleware({
  serializableCheck: false,
});

export const setupStore = () => {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    middleware: customizedMiddleware,
  });
};

export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof setupStore>;
export type AppState = ReturnType<AppStore['getState']>;
export type AppDispatch = AppStore['dispatch'];
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  AppState,
  unknown,
  Action
>;

export const wrapper = createWrapper<AppStore>(setupStore);
```

My `app.tsx` file

```js
import React from 'react';
import AdapterDateFns from '@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';

import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import { setupStore, wrapper } from '../store/store';

export default wrapper.withRedux(function MyApp({
  Component,
  pageProps,
}: AppProps) {
  const persistor = persistStore(setupStore());
  return (
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor} loading={<div>Loading</div>}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </PersistGate>
  );
});
```

It's saving the initial state to local storage but it isn't saving future changes to the state.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Hello. Yes but for my case i didn't need to use that in server side. I just leaved it in client side and for me it working fine

Comment: That's great. I am getting two stores in dev tools one is persisted another is my regular store. Am I supposed to access the persisted store for persistent data? I cannot keep the persisted and regular data in sync when I use the persisted state/reducer data. The issue is the same as you've mentioned. I can't update the storage data. Any help from you would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Posted answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i found solution for me:

```
import {
  Action,
  combineReducers,
  configureStore,
  ThunkAction,
  getDefaultMiddleware,
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  // your reducers
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const customizedMiddleware = getDefaultMiddleware({
  serializableCheck: false,
});

export const setupStore = () => {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    middleware: customizedMiddleware,
  });
};

export const persistedStore = () => persistStore(setupStore());

export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof setupStore>;
export type AppState = ReturnType<AppStore['getState']>;
export type AppDispatch = AppStore['dispatch'];
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  AppState,
  unknown,
  Action
>;

export const store = setupStore();
```

**Warning: your reducers must have this extra reducer like that:**

```
extraReducers: {
[HYDRATE]: (state, action) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    ...action.payload.chatRoom,
  };
},
```

Also i don't know if it will work with SSR because i don't need that feature in my case

Answer (score 1):

You can also add the next-redux-cookie-wrapper plugin of next-redux-wrapper library.

```
export const pageSlice = createSlice({
    name: "page",

    initialState: {title: "", subtitle: "", counter: 0, locale: "en"},

    reducers: {
        increaseCounter(state) {
            state.counter += 1;
        },
        setTitle(state, {payload}: PayloadAction<{title: string; subtitle: string}>) {
            state.counter += 1;
            Object.assign(state, payload);
        },
        setLocale(state, {payload}: PayloadAction<string>) {
            state.locale = payload;
        },
    },

    extraReducers(builder) {
        builder.addCase<typeof HYDRATE, PayloadAction<AppState, typeof HYDRATE>>(
            HYDRATE,
            (state, {payload}) => ({...state, ...payload.page})
        );
    },
});

export const setTitleWithDelay: ActionCreator<AppThunkAction> =
    (title: string, subtitle: string) => async (dispatch) => {
        await delay(300);
        dispatch(pageSlice.actions.setTitle({title, subtitle}));
    };

export const selectPage = (state: AppState) => state[pageSlice.name];

const makeStore = wrapMakeStore(() =>
    configureStore({
        reducer: {
            [pageSlice.name]: pageSlice.reducer,
        },
        middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
            getDefaultMiddleware().prepend(
                nextReduxCookieMiddleware({
                    subtrees: [
                        `${pageSlice.name}.counter`,
                        {
                            subtree: `${pageSlice.name}.locale`,
                            cookieName: "NEXT_LOCALE",
                            serializationFunction: String,
                            deserializationFunction: String,
                            defaultState: pageSlice.getInitialState().locale,
                        },
                    ],
                })
            ),
    })
);

export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof makeStore>;
export type AppState = ReturnType<AppStore["getState"]>;
export type AppDispatch = AppStore["dispatch"];
export type AppThunkAction<ReturnType = Promise<void>> = ThunkAction<
    ReturnType,
    AppState,
    unknown,
    AnyAction
>;

export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();

export const wrapper = createWrapper<AppStore>(makeStore, {debug: true});
```

Check the full demo here (work with SSR)
https://github.com/bjoluc/next-redux-cookie-wrapper/blob/main/demo/store.ts